# solr gives same score for different values

Tags: solr, lucene

I have field type defined in my schema.xml such as follows;

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Here is my field;

```
<dynamicField name="*_text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

When I query the value "am26" in solr admin query board, I am having following results in my document. (There are many fields exist however, I just select code_text and score fields to show)

```
"response": {
"numFound": 6,
"start": 0,
"maxScore": 1184.7297,
"docs": [
  {
    "code_text": "AM232",
    "score": 1184.7297
  },
  {
    "code_text": "AM238",
    "score": 1184.7297
  },
  {
    "code_text": "AM266",
    "score": 1184.7297
  },
  {
    "code_text": "AM268",
    "score": 1184.7297
  },
  {
    "code_text": "AM269",
    "score": 1184.7297
  },
  {
    "code_text": "AM273",
    "score": 1184.7297
  },
]
```

How come score of AM232 and AM266 could be the same ? Furthermore, how come we can see values like AM232 and AM273 among the results ?  Far as I aware when we query "am26" solr first converts this string into lower case (according to definition in schema.xml) and WordDelimiterFilterFactory splits string as am,26. So I can understand the results which includes 26 and AM but I don't know why I see "AM232" and "AM273" in my document. Plus they have exact score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your search terms will be: "am" and "26"

However, there is no wildcard involved in this search.  All of the results given match the "am" part, but *none* of them match "26".  For "AM266", the indexed terms are "am" and "266".  But the term "26" is still not a match for "266".  I expect if you had a document "AM26", you would indeed see that get a higher score that the others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although document AM266 is not exact match for the search term AM26, it has higher hit. 4 characters are matching. The main point that I am struggling to understand is  how come AM232 and AM266 has exact same score. I would expect AM232 to less score comparing with AM266.

Comment: As I said, the term "26" matches *none* of the documents.  The term "26" matches the term "266" exactly as well as it matches "steve", which is to say, not at all.

Comment: For your: `4 characters are matching` -> this is wrong. Only `AM` will match. You can use analysis tool in solr admin page to observe that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer alexf and femtoRgon. I changed my query such as like that code_sortabletext:(am26*^150.0) and it works now. I needed to boost that field with the value of 150 because there are other fields which has some values makes noise in the search and priority is the code field for me. Thanks very much again.